# Remove ZLE commands from zsh autocomplete

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I've set up zsh completion to be case-insensitive, and I use the `autocd` option, so when I type `downl<Tab><Enter>` I will `cd Downloads/`. Great! However, if I just type `dow`, zsh will instead autocomplete `down-case-word-match`, which appears to be a function in ZLE. After a bit of digging I tried adding to my `.zshrc` (after `compinit`) the following line:

```
unset '_comps[_zle]'
```

However, the offending completion is still there. So how do I remove ZLE suggestions from autocomplete?

Comment: Please don’t crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75478175/remove-zle-commands-from-zsh-autocomplete

Comment: This is IMHO not the default behavior. Try to break your .zshrc file down to the line which changes this behavior.

Comment: You're totally right, my question was one of those classic "I have a 100 line zshrc and something has gone wrong" :(  I figured out the solution and posted it here in case it's useful to someone else in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of this issue was two lines in my `.zshrc` [commonly recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60587656/6220759) to get bash-style word boundaries:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style bash
```

This autoloads several functions (listed [here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/select-word-style#L6)), including `down-case-word-match`.

Since I wanted to keep this but was just bothered by one specific function, I removed it from completion by adding (after `compinit`)

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:-command-:*:*' ignored-patterns 'down-case-word-match'
```

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/533062/398544).